# The Microsoft Graph API, create attachment does not works?

Tags: javascript, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create an attachment when I'm going to post a message. I followed the document as below and testing the api, but it doesn't works!!

http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/post_post_attachments

My JavaScript code is as below:

```
obj.createAttachment = function (groupId, threadId, postId) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    var s = Base64.encode("one drive");
    HttpClient.post({
        url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupId + "/threads/" + threadId + "/posts/" + postId + "/attachments",
        data: {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
            "Name": "test_one_drive.txt",
            "ContentType": "text/plain",
            "IsInline": true,
            "ContentLocation": "https://wiadvancetechology.sharepoint.com/sites/wiogroup85/Shared%20Documents/test%20one%20drive.txt",
            "ContentBytes": s
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        d.resolve(response);
    });
    return d.promise;
};
```

But the response always show "405 (Method Not Allowed)".
The error message is "The OData request is not supported."

Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: If you look at the documentation all properties use camel casing whereas in your example you're using Pascal casing. Could you try changing the casing of the properties to camel casing and see if it helps?

Comment: I changed the casing to camel casing, but it still not working. The changing is like "name", "contentType", "isInline", "contentLocation", "contentBytes"

Comment: The response error message is "The OData request is not supported."

Comment: Does this file already exist in One Drive?  If it does, you might have to use the PATCH method rather than POST to update it.

Comment: It could be that this operation is currently unsupported: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/72#issuecomment-163311210

Comment: Another reason can be a wrong path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62356523/a-post-call-to-add-a-new-opentypeextension-to-event-data-fails-with-resource-no/66885162#66885162

Answer (score 1):

The "The OData request is not supported" error message is caused by a bug. A fix for it is being rolled out and should be widely available in about a month. We're also adding a note to the release notes.

Please also note that the @odata.type in your code should be "microsoft.graph.fileAttachment". The "Microsoft.OutlookServices" namespace should only be used with the Outlook API/endpoint and not the MS Graph API/endpoint.