# A post call to add a new openTypeExtension to event data fails with “Resource not found for the segment 'extensions'”

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to add an extension to the event resource using Graph Explorer. I am using `POST` on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/event/extensions with request body

```
{
   "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName": "com.wrike.WrikeIDs",
    "id": "",
    "permalink": ""
}
```

I get the error

> "Resource not found for the segment 'event'"

and sometimes I get

> "The OData request is not supported"

Content type is `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

The error message might be misleading.

Try to adjust the path to

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event_id}/extensions`